# React native android/setting can't complie

Tags: react-native

i am getting error in settings.gradel .
settings file 'C:\Users\abhi\abhilash\floatbutton\android\settings.gradle':

```
3: unexpected char: 
project(':react-native-vector-icons').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '..\node_modules\react-native-vector-icons\android')

showing error in // \react-native-vector-icons\android')  /android.



rootProject.name = 'floatbutton'
include ':react-native-vector-icons'
project(':react-native-vector-icons').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '..\node_modules\react-native-vector-icons\android')

include ':app'
```

Comment: please format your code.. this looks awful.

Answer (score 0):

this might be a bug with the latest gradlew or react native link , idk, but everytime i need to install a native android module i get this error. the solution for me is to go to the folder Android and open settings.gradle, then replace all \ with /

Go to "C:\Users\abhi\abhilash\floatbutton\android\" in your case.

Open settings.gradle with a text editor

replace `'..\node_modules\react-native-vector-icons\android'` with `'../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/android'`

Save and enjoy